# How to fix ModuleNotFound error in python building?

Tags: python, github, building

I trying to build the ungoogled chrome source from github.  I was following the instructions in the link below, but I really do not know how to continue.

I installed python 2.7 and 3.7, set them in the PATH.

Used the `git clone` command and **jumped** the `replace` comands and the git `checkout` too, because I didin't got them.

> So, I tried the "py build.py" command and got this error.
>
> ```
> C:\Users\aquasp\ungoogled-chromium-windows>py build.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "build.py", line 24, in <module>
>     import buildkit.config
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'buildkit'
> ```

Is there any suggestions?

This are the commands that I was folowing:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium-windows.git
# Replace TAG_OR_BRANCH_HERE with a tag or branch name
git checkout --recurse-submodules TAG_OR_BRANCH_HERE
py build.py
py package.py
```

https://github.com/ungoogled-software/ungoogled-chromium-windows

Comment: So, have you replaced TAG_OR_BRANCH_HERE?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are on a windows machine. Try running the dos 'which' command with an argument of 'buildkit' as follows:

---

which buildkit

---

The output will be the search of directories in the path variable of the windows machine as follows:

---

which: no buildkit in (/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1
etc...

---

'buildkit' is not found on path or the python.exe is not on the path.

---

Try 'which python' or 'which py' to test for python.exe or py in the machine path.
if python.exe is found output is as follows:

---

/c/Program Files/python/python

---

or if not found

---

which: no python found in (/c/WINDOWS/system32: etc...

---

Last but not least, add buildkit or python.exe or py to your machines path variable as follows:

---

set path=%path%;plus\new\path

---

C:\Users>echo %path%

---

C:\WINDOWS\system32;plus\new\path